# regarding proper way of broadcasting input array from one shape into another shape

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

There is a function, I got the following message while calling this function

The function is to resize a given image set, and put the transformed ones into the new set `imgs_p`.

For instance, the input `imgs` has shape `(5635,1,420,580)`. I want to transform it `(5635,64,80,1)`. This is what I did as follows, but i got the error message as `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (80,64) into shape (80,1)`

How to solve this problem? Thanks.

```
def preprocess(imgs):
    imgs_p = np.ndarray((imgs.shape[0],img_rows, img_cols,imgs.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
    print('imgs_p: ',imgs_p.shape)
for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):
    print('imgs[i,0]: ',imgs[i,0].shape)
    imgs_p[i,0]=resize(imgs[i,0],(img_rows,img_cols))
return imgs_p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want to roll the "1" dimension to the correct position:

```
z = np.moveaxis(z, 1, -1).shape
```

whereafter you can run a for-loop over each image and reshape, either using skimage or scipy.ndimage.

Be careful with downsampling!  You probably want to apply a Gaussian blur first to make sure all the data is taken into account.